# Use WebView from within sendAsynchronousRequest?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am making an asynchronous request in Objective-C via the following method:

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    NSInteger code = [httpResponse statusCode];
    if (code == 200){
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        // Escape single quotes
        jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\'"];
        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"window.displayVotes('%@')", jsonString]];
    } else {
        // Error
        ...
    }
}];
```

This code preforms fine until I reach `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`, where the code exits with the following info:

```
1   0x7fff891faf1f WebCore::ScriptController::evaluateInWorld(WebCore::ScriptSourceCode const&, WebCore::DOMWrapperWorld*)
2   0x7fff891fadc9 WebCore::ScriptController::evaluate(WebCore::ScriptSourceCode const&)
3   0x7fff89338466 WebCore::ScriptController::executeScript(WebCore::ScriptSourceCode const&)
4   0x7fff89338290 WebCore::ScriptController::executeScript(WTF::String const&, bool)
5   0x7fff8c85265e -[WebFrame(WebInternal) _stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:forceUserGesture:]
6   0x100008fc9 __31-[CCAppDelegate getVotes:name:]_block_invoke
7   0x7fff90da26ad __67+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2
8   0x7fff90c2c0b5 -[NSBlockOperation main]
9   0x7fff90c0b8a1 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:]
10  0x7fff90c0b54b __NSOQSchedule_f
11  0x7fff915a62ad _dispatch_client_callout
12  0x7fff915aa7ff _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke
13  0x7fff915a62ad _dispatch_client_callout
14  0x7fff915a809e _dispatch_root_queue_drain
15  0x7fff915a9193 _dispatch_worker_thread2
16  0x7fff8d179ef8 _pthread_wqthread
17  0x7fff8d17cfb9 start_wqthread
```

I'm not entirely sure why this is happening (hence my coming to SO), but my guess is that is has to do with the availability of `self.webView` to a different thread. I would keep it as a synchronous request, except the URL that I request might take a while to return, which consequently blocks up the UI.

Is there any way to remedy this? I attempted moving the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` code to it's own method, and then calling `[self thatMethod]` within the completion callback, but it produced a similar error.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the tip. I ended up just using `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` and that solved it. If you want to post that as an answer I'll mark it and upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might encourage you to keep the connection asynchronous, but try dispatching the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` to the main queue (or use `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` as the `queue` parameter of `sendAsynchronousRequest`; the `queue` parameter specifies which queue the completion block will run on, but the original request still runs asynchronously).

This way, you preserve the asynchronous nature of the request, but ensure that the web view interaction happens on the main queue.